# AngularJS ng-click attribute not updating on post request within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ajax, post, get, pug

This is the pug file for the catalog

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title Tradecademy
        meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
        script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js")
        script(src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular-sanitize.min.js")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat")
        link(href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css", rel="stylesheet", integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh", crossorigin="anonymous")
        script(src="./includes/catalog.js")
    body(ng-app="catalog" ng-controller="catalogController")
        include ./includes/appheader.pug
        .w3-display-container
            ul.w3-ul
                li
                    h2 Beginner Modules
                li
                    div(ng-repeat=("module in beginnerModules"))
                       | {{module.name}}
                       button.w3-button.w3-blue.w3-hover-teal(ng-click="buyCourse(\"{{module.name}}\")")
                li
                    h2 Advanced Modules
```

This is the catalog.js file

```
var app = angular.module('catalog', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller("catalogController", ($scope, $http) => {
  $http({
    method : 'GET',
    url : '/catalogModules'

  }).then((response)=> {
    if(response.data.undefined == "undefined") {
      window.location.href="/"
    }
    else 
    {
      $scope.headerArray = []

      angular.forEach(response, (value) => {
        $scope.headerArray.push(value);
      });

      $scope.modules = $scope.headerArray[0];
      $scope.beginnerModules = []
      $scope.advancedModules =[]
      angular.forEach($scope.modules, (value) => {

        if(value.type == "Beginner") 
        {
          $scope.beginnerModules.push(value);
        }
        if(value.type == "Advanced") 
        {
          $scope.advancedModules.push(value);
        }
      });
    }
  $scope.buyCourse = (module) => {
        console.log(module);
        $http.post("/buyNewModule", module)
        .success(function (data, status, headers) {
          console.log($scope.beginnerCourseKey);
          console.log(data);
          console.log(status);
          console.log(headers);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, header) {
          console.log($scope.beginnerCourseKey);
          console.log(data);
          console.log(header);
          console.log(status);
        });
      }
  });
});
```

The issue is when it should be logging the module's name attribute, it logs "{{module.name}}". I need to be able to access the actual name value instead of the AngularJS Interpolation. I'm pretty new to AngularJS so if I'm doing anything wrong, please let me know. The GET function works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the new pug file.

```
.w3-display-container
            ul.w3-ul
                li
                    h2 Beginner Modules
                li
                    div(ng-repeat=("module in beginnerModules"))
                       button.w3-button.w3-blue.w3-hover-teal(ng-click="buyCourse(module.name)")
                li
                    h2 Advanced Modules
```

I'm not sure why it did this as I tried doing - var moduleName = module.name and it gave me the error that module is undefined. Any insights on why this worked would be nice.